# Having hard time understanding SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I ran across this query and having hard time understanding what it does

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME,
    EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME,
    COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEE 
JOIN ENTRY ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = ENTRY.EMPLOYEE_ID
JOIN TICKET ON ENTRY.TICKET_ID = TICKET.TICKET_ID 
WHERE ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID = 'ADVTS' AND EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT_ID ='SLS'
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID,  EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME,
    EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME,ENTRY.ENTRY_ID
HAVING COUNT(ENTRY.ENTRY_ID) >= 
(SELECT CAST(1.25 * COUNT(ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID)/COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID) AS float) 
FROM 
  EMPLOYEE 
JOIN 
  ENTRY ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = ENTRY.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE 
  ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID = 'ADVTS' AND EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT_ID = 'SLS')
```

As far as I understand it gives a list of `EMPLOYEE`s who done `ADVTS` `ACTIVITY` and from `DEPARTMENT` `SLS` which made `ENTRY`s at least as much as Average entries made in the `DEPARTMENT` `SLS` for `ADVTS` purposes

Thanks to anyone who take their time to help

Edit succesful result after comments:

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME,
    EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME
    FROM EMPLOYEE
JOIN 
  ENTRY ON ENTRY.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
GROUP 
   BY EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE.LAST_NAME,
    EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME
HAVING 
  COUNT(ENTRY.ENTRY_ID) >= 
(SELECT 
  CAST(1.25 * 
  COUNT(ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID)/COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID)AS float) 
FROM 
  EMPLOYEE JOIN ENTRY ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = ENTRY.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE 
  ENTRY.ACTIVITY_ID = 'ADVTS' AND EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT_ID = 'SLS')
```

OUTPUT:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID| LAST_NAME| FIRST_NAME
7          | Salesman | Efficient
```

Comment: Don't try. Any time you see a query with both a `SELECT DISTINCT ` and an aggregate function, you can be reasonably confident that it's gibberish.

Comment: @Strawberry could please give some reasons?

Comment: I think the query is supposed to do what you suggested.  Except that the ENTRY.ENTRY_ID shouldn't be in the GROUP BY I guess.  And it takes all the employees that have 25% more than average activities.

Comment: Yes @Wouter I just realized this. Also I don't think there is any need to JOIN `TICKET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `TICKET_ID` is unique in `Ticket` and is never `NULL` in `ENTRY`, then you can get rid of that `JOIN`.

Then I assume the purpose of the query is to return employees whose count is more than 1.25 the overall average.  That requires a few more (reasonable) assumptions, but this is more simply written as:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT EM.EMPLOYEE_ID, EM.LAST_NAME, EM.FIRST_NAME, COUNT(*) AS CNT,   
             SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER () as AVG_CNT    
      FROM EMPLOYEE EM JOIN
           ENTRY EM
           ON EM.EMPLOYEE_ID = EN.EMPLOYEE_ID 
      WHERE EN.ACTIVITY_ID = 'ADVTS' AND EM.DEPARTMENT_ID = 'SLS'
      GROUP BY EM.EMPLOYEE_ID, EM.LAST_NAME, EM.FIRST_NAME
     ) e
WHERE cnt >= 1.25 * avg_cnt
```